# UIActionsheet Ipad/Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiactionsheet

I'm currently using a UIActionsheet for my universal app, works great and all, but I want the iPad actionsheet to resemble the iPhone actionsheet.

Is there anything on the iPad that is similar to the iPhone actionsheet? Alternatively, is there a way to reposition the iPad actionsheet and popoverview WITHOUT a direction arrow?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is the code where I implement and add the actionsheet

```
adActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Go to Site", @"Some other button", nil];
    [adActionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(300, 1150, 200, 200) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an iPad, action sheets are automatically shown in a popover. This can't be changed. You can't remove the array either. The `UIActionSheet` API doesn't support what you want.

Your only solution is a custom implementation that does what you want.

Comment: Although I would've liked some sort of simple alternative, this works as well. Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can remove arrow from UIPopover in ipad

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:anItem   
                                permittedArrowDirections:0
                                                animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self.popoverViewController presentPopoverFromRect:rect
 inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

The zero represent no direction.

Comment: `permittedArrowDirection` shouldn't be zero. You need to use one  mentioned here.. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIPopoverArrowDirection. Try changing it to `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown` instead.

Comment: Would I have access to the popoverViewController options since my actionsheet automatically is transformed into a popover? I edited the original post to include a snippet of code.

Comment: From the documentation link, above: “You must not specify `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown` for this parameter.”

Comment: Do not set to `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown` as mentioned in the documentation *"You must not specify UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown for this parameter"*. Thanks @ZevEisenberg for pointing it out.

Comment: @Steve No, `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp` is defined as `1UL << 0` which is equal to 1, not 0. That's 1 left shifted zero times.